# In a android launcher, how can I block access to some App?

Tags: java, android, package, launcher

I need to create one launcher for Android written in Java. This launcher will be a safe place for kids. I've managed to create a local database with all label and packages of the installed app.

Now whenever the user click on an icon (you can see what I mean with picture's link), I would like my launcher to check the user has the right to open it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nnGo.png]

Could you please help me or give me some indications?

I've checked on the internet and tried DevicePolicyManager with `setPackagesSuspended()` but I didn't manage to make it work. I've also seen the broadcast receiver but I don't know if it will work.

**Edit** : I'm trying to do it with a Broadcast receiver, do you know if there is an intent-filter that trigger when a package is launch ?

Comment: If the launcher is created by you, then it should be easy, try to check the user type, if appropriate, then open app otherwise don't, or even you can just don't show the app to the user if its a child.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes I've made the launcher. And I can hide App I want. But on the picture, you will see that user can still acess to the settings, I would like to block this access.

Comment: That Settings icon is part of the System UI. You need to do some changes at the ROM level to affect that. Are you planning on using a specific device? If you are just creating a launcher you cannot do this.

Comment: Currently, there is a launcher called Kid's Shell. And where you are using Kid Mode, you cannot access to the settings even with this button.

Comment: So I've managed to find a solution. I've created an Async task that check what app is in foreground. If I don't want user to get on this app, I will send it to back to my launcher main screen.